# Gson import error in Scala.

Tags: json, scala, parsing, gson

I am using a Gson library for parsing Json data. I am trying to run a program from terminal as follows:

```
scala -classpath "*.jar" JsonParsing.scala
```

To which I am getting the following error:

```
JsonParsing.scala:2: error: object google is not a member of package com import com.google.gson.Gson
```

I am unsure as why this error is coming. When I have gson jar in accurate folder.

```
gson-2.2.2.jar
```

I am using import statements as follows:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonParser
```

Help on this error would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your dependancy not include google package.

You can use :

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.0"
```

or download appropriate jar `http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/gson.htm`

Answer (score 0):

**Compile:**

`$ scalac -classpath <path_to_your_jar_files> -d classes " path/to/classes/you/want/to/compile/*`

**Execute:**

`$ scala -classpath classes:<path_to_your_jar_files> com.your.package.ClassYouWantToRun`

This is not a good way of doing it because it's not scalable. You should be using a tool like [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) to build and run projects.

Comment: I am getting the same error on compilation. @YongSpice

Comment: You need to provide your directory structure. Anything without it would be guesswork. Also the code you pasted is `scala ....`, not `scalac ....`